# Why can't I find the moment $t_1$ where the radioactivity is gone?

Tags: radiation, radioactivity, half-life

Let's say $t_1$ is the moment the radioactivity is gone:

$A(t_1) = A_0 e^{-kt}$

$A(t_1) = 0$ since it's gone

But then what? How do I find $t_1$?

Since $A_0 e^{-kt} = 0$ then I can't "$\ln$" both of sides because there is no such thing as "$\ln(0)$"

So what do I do?

Answer (score 2):

That is because there is no finite $t_1$ such that $A(t_1)=0$. That is precisely what the math is telling you. $A(t)$ gets closer and closer to 0, but it never reaches it. It only approaches 0 asymptotically.

Comment: So what should I write then? Positive 0?

Comment: @TechnoKnight 0 isn’t positive. The equation can be solved for any positive number, so not 0.

Comment: I meant by "Positive 0" something like "0.000001"

Comment: @TechnoKnight sure, you could solve it for 0.000001 using the $\ln$ as you were planning. Instead of looking for the radiation to be “gone” you are just looking for it to be negligible.

Comment: You know 0 isn't the right answer, since after 0 s there should still be a lot of radioactivity (the radioactivity gets less over time).